# Why did Zaza only "bid farewell" to the possibility of going to Moscow?

Tags: georgian-language, lasha-bugadze, the-literature-express

When Zaza was looking at the itinerary for the Literature Express, he noticed that Kaliningrad and Moscow were stops; he "immediately bade farewell" to Moscow since Georgians were denied visas to go to Russia. This makes sense given that relations between Georgia and Russia were severed following the latter's [vicious and unprovoked attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Georgian_War) on the former in 2008.

However, Kaliningrad (which was one stop before Moscow) is also in Russia; why did the narrator only comment on Moscow? Presumably if he couldn't go to Moscow he couldn't go to Kaliningrad for the same reason.